# Accessing a control which is in a contentpresenter in c#

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp, contentpresenter

How to access a named control that is in the content template of the contentpresenter. how to access the webview control(x:name=detView) from cs file.

```
        <ContentPresenter
            x:Name="DetailContentPresenter"
            Grid.Row="0"
            BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseLowBrush}"
            Content="{x:Bind coll.SelectedItem,Mode=OneWay}">
            <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:coll_Details" x:Name="ttt">
                    <Grid>
                           <WebView DefaultBackgroundColor="#F5F5F5" x:Name="detView" Source="ms-appx-web:///Assets/Web/collDetails.html"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter.ContentTransitions>
                <TransitionCollection/>
            </ContentPresenter.ContentTransitions>
        </ContentPresenter>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ContentPresenter as ControlTemplate like the example of [Official Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br209378(v=win.10).aspx?appid=dev14idef1&l=en-us&k=k(windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentpresenter)%3bk(vs.xamleditor)%3bk(targetframeworkmoniker-.netcore,version%3dv5.0)&rd=true).

You can get the template through the `controlName.ContentTemplateRoot`. I made a demo from the Example of official documentation above, and put a webview inside the DataTemplate.

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="HyperlinkButton" x:Key="myStyle" >
        ...
        <Setter Property="Template" x:Name="presenterSetter">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
                    <Grid x:Name="rootGrid">
                        ...
                        <Border x:Name="Border"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Margin="3">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                          ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                        >
                                <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate  x:Name="ttt">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <WebView Source="ms-appx-web:///Assets/Web/default.html" Name="myWebView"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Border>
                        <!--focus visuals omitted-->
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <HyperlinkButton Name="myHyperlink" Style="{StaticResource myStyle}">This is a link</HyperlinkButton>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Name="myBtn">Click Me</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And I can get the WebView using the codes below:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var myView= ((Grid)myHyperlink.ContentTemplateRoot).Children[0] as WebView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#, use this code to find any control which is present in your `ContentPresenter`.

If a `TextBlock` is present in your `ContentPresenter` then first create a object of the `TextBlock` then cast it and then find control.

```
TextBlock myTextBlock = (TextBlock)ttt.FindName(“textBlock”, DetailContentPresenter);
```