# How to access a named TextBlock in a button XAML C# UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, datatemplate, textblock

I changed my UWP application to have a responsive UI.
Since then I have a problem to put text in a button.
Here's the XAML:

```
    <Page
    x:Class="Stock_Manager_Windows.IncomeOrder3"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Stock_Manager_Windows"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="#FFBBBBBB">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            ...
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            ...
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
...
        <Button x:Name="Envoyer" Content="Envoyer" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2,2,0,2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="4" Background="#249C23" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Click="buttonSendSelectedItems_Click">
            <Button.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Name="EnvoyerDataTemplate" >
                    <Viewbox>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="EnvoyerTxt" Text="Envoyer"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Button.ContentTemplate>
        </Button>
...
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Before the modif I used to update the text in the button with this C# code :

```
Envoyer.Content = "Envoyer (" + count + ")";
```

Now its not possible...
Then at first I tried with :

```
envoyerTxt.Text = "Envoyer (" + count + ")";
```

I tried to use the solutions explained with the following links, but it seems the code is obsolete, not related or I'm too stupid to understand it.

[WPF How to access control from DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586106/wpf-how-to-access-control-from-datatemplate)

[Accessing a control which is in a contentpresenter in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38196392/accessing-a-control-which-is-in-a-contentpresenter-in-c-sharp)

[How do I access a control inside a XAML DataTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375375/how-do-i-access-a-control-inside-a-xaml-datatemplate)

[how to access a control within Data Template from code behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379946/how-to-access-a-control-within-data-template-from-code-behind)

[FindVisualChild reference issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229503/findvisualchild-reference-issue/25229554#25229554)

Is someone could explain me the solution ?
Maybe the problem is not in c# code but in the XAML, I have no clues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `ContentTemplate` change the `TextBlock` to this.

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="EnvoyerTxt" Text="{Binding}" />
```

Which means now, whatever content (Text) is set it will be bind to your template `TextBlock` text property and it will change accordingly.

To make it also clear, You can not access an element by it's name inside a template. Because templates are loaded at runtime and not at compile time. That's why inside templates only binding will work for assigning data.

Comment: OK, big THANK YOU @Rao Hammas !